# How can I send user ID in Angular using both REST API and websockets

Tags: javascript, django, angular, typescript

I am going to create chatbot using websockets. Each user can have their own account. I have Django backend and frontend written in Angular. I am not sure how can I send my `user_id` from frontend to backend, because I use in my project both Django Rest Framework and websockets, so it seems to me that frontend has to authenticate user both using websockets and REST and has to know that it is the same one user. However it seems to me that it is impossible to have one common authentication for REST and websockets. 
This is example JSON data that my backend has to receive:

```
{
"user_id":2,
"message":"My message"
}
```

Any ideas how can I solve it?
This is part of my Angular component:

```
export class HomeComponent {

    response: string;
    response2: string;

    constructor(
        private chatService: ChatService,
        private router: Router,
        private http: Http,
    ) {

        chatService.messages.subscribe(msg => {
            this.response = msg.message;
      console.log("Response from backend: " + msg.message);
        });

    }
    private message = {
        message: 'this is a test message'
    }

  sendMsg() {
        console.log('new message from client to websocket: ', this.message);
        this.chatService.messages.next(this.message);
        return this.message.message;
    }

  send(msg) {
     this.message.message = msg;
     this.sendMsg();
  }

      login() {
        return this.http.get('/data', )
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(response2 => this.response2 = response2);
    }
```

Comment: You can store the logged in user id in `localStorage` for common usage from both websockets and by Angular http client.

Comment: @SachinKukreja can you show me how can I do that?

Comment: You can either directly use it by accessing `window.localStorage` setter and getter methods or install a package in Angular for `localStorage` API.